# WRAP_CONTENT not not wrapping up the listview width in android

Tags: android, listview

I have a `listView` which contains a list of app icons.I am trying to set `listview` height and width programmatically like this:

```
listView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

But the width of the `listView` is not wrapping up according to the width of the app icons.It is just simply covering the whole screen.
I have implemented the `listView` on simple `LinearLayout`.Is there any solution.

I am using `listview`in service with `windowManager` so I set its height and width by code like this:

First of all I have set the linear layout height and width like this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams listParam=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            80, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    listLinear.setLayoutParams(listParam); //listLinear is my linearLayout
```

after I added listview inside the linearLayout:

```
listView.setId(listId);
    listView.setAdapter(listadapter);
    listView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(80, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));    
    listLinear.addView(listView);
```

I want to replace 80 with WRAP_CONTENT as a width.

Comment: can you show layout.xml for the list-view? And maybe the xml of the rows

Comment: Please post the XML for your list view item layout.

Comment: Why would you want your listview to wrap its width? Usually you use match_parent...

Comment: @JohnnyAW I have updated my question:)

Comment: @JoseBernhardt I have updated my question:)

Comment: @AbAppletic I want my listview width to WRAP_content.Because i dont want it to cover my whole screen

Comment: What about your adapter getView method? can you share it?

Comment: Please post the XML where you have your layout linked to the ListView, as @AbAppletic mentioned, match_parent should be use for the width and height, at least thats how I use it

Comment: @Jose Bernhardt OK I will try setting match parent but if I set match parent doesn't it will cover the entire screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on the ListView XML:

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:divider="#bdbdbd"
android:dividerHeight="3.0sp"
android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
android:paddingEnd="7dp"
android:paddingStart="7dp"></ListView>
```

I have this listview inside a FrameLayout, but you can try to have it inside a RelativeLayout.

Comment: OK thanks a lot I will try it and tell you the result:)